# Adding fixed point integers in two's Compments

Tags: twos-complement

I was referring a past paper for a exam then I found this. I am confused about this question. Help would be great.

Add the following numbers as fixed point integers.Your calculations must be shown by using binary numbers in two's complement

-9.25+(-2.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase `fixed point integers` (where a number is generally *either* fixed-point or an integer) leads me to believe it's really just a scaled integer.

In other words, the actual representation of those numbers would be `-925` and `-250` (with a scale of `100`).

So I would think the process would be to convert those to binary, do the two's complement addition, then convert back to decimal, hopefully giving `-1175` would would scale to `-11.75`).